# Whose red seal is on this work?

Tags: translation, seal

I saw a painting from a thrift shop, and am curious to know who the artist is. Here is the seal:[image]

Answer (score 3):

sightly derived from standard seal script, imo

the top seal is “樂壽”, roughly means happiness (樂), longevity (壽)

the bottom one is “美都子”,  likely a name

have fun :)